# Store incoming request in replay-able way

Tags: php, symfony, curl, request, replay

I am currently debugging my public api using symfony 3.x and seem to run into some edge case errors that are hard to reproduce.

Therefore I would like to store incoming requests in a way that lets me replay the failed/erroneous request later in debugging (thus maintaining all headers, body, domain of origin, ... ).

Ideally I was looking for a solution that works with common tools like curl to let me replay the request. Apparently there is no such thing and the closest I could fathom was to build a tool myself that would dump out a curl command that somewhat resembles the original request.

Given that I am not totally versed in curl that option seems rather error prone.

I honestly hoped this would be a solved problem in the world of api development and hope one of you can point me in the right direction.

Best regards !

[Update: Edited to indicate use of symfony]

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar problem, and I am thinking about storing all the request data as well as response data in relational DB with some unique ID in it.

After that we can expose a API that will take those Unique IDs in one go and we can register a async task to replay those requests with stored Data.

Async Framework - Celery\n
DB - PostgreSQL(Debatable)

Comment: Most bug tracking tools (not going to name any specifics) stores the incoming request and lets you replay them for debugging purposes.